# Is there a way to modify SystemTime in rust?

Tags: rust, systemtime

I need to modify a `SystemTime` and set it to the current minute without the seconds but I can't find any methods or documentation on how to do this. I am currently using `SystemTime::now()`. What I am looking for is some way to set the seconds to zero. Is there a way to do this in rust?

Comment: You can't do that without chrono. And even with some trick what you ask don't make sense. SystemTime is not mean to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SystemTime is not really designed as a full datetime library - it sounds like you probably want something like the [chrono](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) or [time](https://crates.io/crates/time) crates.